# Error: Could not find or load main class in MCScanX

Tags: java

I did

1. `git clone https://github.com/wyp1125/MCScanX.git`
2. cd MCScanX
3. make

Next, I ran into this problem:

```
java /lustre/scratch/team/MCScanX/app/MCScanX/downstream_analyses/dot_plotter -g xyz.gff -s xyz.collinearity -c dot.ctl -o dot_plotter.png
Error: Could not find or load main class .lustre.scratch.team.MCScanX.app.MCScanX.downstream_analyses.dot_plotter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /lustre/scratch/team/MCScanX/app/MCScanX/downstream_analyses/dot_plotter
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Clone the `ssh` link instead of `https`

```
git clone git@github.com:wyp1125/MCScanX.git
cd MCScanX
make
```

Comment: Thank you, I could compile the code but during java execution I got `Error: Could not find or load main class....`. What did I miss?